# Login Screen kivy/kivymd

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating an app using python (kivy and kivymd) and I have a login screen but every time I open my application I will get this screen,how can I make to appear once and disappear permanently?

Comment: John Anderson thank you for your help , i tried to make the code for screen but i stocked at some point

Comment: if anyone there who have faced this problem before and have the solution please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use a [config file](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#application-configuration) to store the information to decide whether to open the login screen.

Comment: do you mind if you give me some example on config file please John Anderson

Comment: Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226179/kivy-how-to-keep-widgets-that-are-added-later-when-the-app-restarts/63585250#63585250)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help:

It tries to read a 'temp.txt' file

On first run , there is no such file and an exception will be thrown calling the except block

Code:

```
global k
try:
    with open('temp.txt','r') as file:
        p = file.read()
        global k
        k = False
except:
    global k
    with open('temp.txt','w') as file:
        file.write('1')
    k = True
class Management(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self,*kwargs):
        global k
        if k:
            self.current = 'LoginScreen'
        else:
            self.current = 'HomeScreen'
```